# Proof a single neuron with linear treshold unit as function can't sole XOR problem

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

Suppose that a neural unit with activation function $sign(net) = 1 $ if $ net \geq 0 $, and $0$ otherwise, could solve the XOR problem.

Then we would have weights $w_1,w_2$ and a bias $b$ such that

$1\times w_1 + 1 \times w_2 + b < 0 $ (since the sign should assign $0$ to $1,1$)

$1\times w_1 + 0 \times w_2 + b \geq 0 $ (since the sign should assign $1$ to $1,0$)

$0\times w_1 + 1 \times w_2 + b \geq 0 $ (since the sign should assign $1$ to $0,1$)

$0\times w_1 + 0 \times w_2 + b < 0 $ (since the sign should assign $0$ to $0,0$)

Should this lead to a contradiction that shows such perceptron can't exist, for instance

if $ b < 0 $ and $w_1 + w_2 + b < 0 $ then

$w_1 + w_2 + 2b < 0 $

and if $w_1 + b \geq 0 $ and $w_2 + b \geq 0 $

then $w_1 + w_2 + 2b \geq 0 $ and this is a contradiction.

Comment: Looks good so far. What's your question? Are you stuck on the $b\ge0$ case?

Comment: It should be sufficient as it is right?  b≥0 is not contemplated as case, since if b were positive, the 0,0 case could never be solved

Comment: Ah yeah, then the proof looks complete to me. Your use of "if" made me think you were doing proofs by cases.

Comment: thanks for the check